# Dynamically scale List Component and its Text contents

Tags: flash, resolution, scaling

I have a list component in my flash application that I wan't to dynamically scale for different resolutions when an event.RESIZE is thrown.

Scaling the actual List is easy enough. I can set the list to a static size for the minimum expected resolution and then scale it up as a ratio of the current resolution to the minimum resolution. Something like:

```
if(stage.stageWidth > MIN_WIDTH_RESOLUTION)
    m_list.width = MIN_LIST_WIDTH * (stage.stageWidth / MIN_WIDTH_RESOLUTION)
```

and something similar for the height.

The problem comes from the textField's inside of the list. The text is not scaling with the list. **Are there any built in ActionScript ways to handle this?**

I tried to do it manually via setting the fontSize of the textFields and the rowHeight of the list in a min ratio manner similar to the code snippet above. I ran into problems because the size of the text can not be determined simply from one dimension. Increasing the size of the font when the width of the stage increases will also increase the height of the font.

It would be awesome if this can be handled internally by actionscript in a method I don't know about, but if not I would appreciate some tips or equations on how to handle this manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transform property of the list to scale or resize it(also its children). What you need to do is, just do the scaling calculations and assign it in a matrix and then assign that matrix to the transform.

Example:
if **mlist** is your list and **matrix** then,

```
mlist.transform.matrix = matrix;
```

The following link help you to set your matrix

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html

I believe this piece of information is what you want exactly.